# Can someone verify the hole diameter is correct?

Tags: pcb, datasheet, through-hole

I'm looking at this current sensor ([datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Tamura%20PDFs/L18PxxxD15.pdf))

I'm a little confused at this notation for hole size.

[image: Datasheet drawing]

Pin 5 and 6 have a diameter of 0.6mm while pin 1, 2, 3, 4 have a diameter of 0.25mm ? Is that correct ?

If someone could also explain what this format is "4-0.25x0.5". I've never seen this type of notation before.

Thanks!

**edit**

I **think** it could be 0.25mm x 0.5mm (length x width) since the pins look more rectangular vs circular for pins [1,4].

Answer (score 1):

I think that diagram gives the pin sizes, not the recommended hole size.  Pins 1 - 4 are 0.25mm x 0.5 mm.  For the 3 amp version, pins 5 and 6 are 0.6 mm diameter.

The drawing below the one you show above shows pins 1 - 4 as small rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that pins 5 & 6 are made of round wire.  Diameter depends on the specific sub-model.  The sub-models for greater current have thicker pins.
(There are also 40A, 50A, 60A sub-models, which have a stamped copper conductor.  The drawing for those sub-models, is on the left side of p.2.)

Pins 1-4 are rectangular (flat, stamped).  Thickness 0.25mm, width 0.5mm, length 5mm.  The nominal hole diameter is the length of the diagonal of the cross-section of the pin.  \$ \sqrt { 0.25^2 + 0.5^2} \approx 0.56\$ mm.  Add an allowance.   I would use a hole with finished diameter 0.81mm (or more).